# How can I control an animated gif in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, gif

Is there any way that I can control an animated GIF in react native (android and ios)?

Or is there any way that I can extract the frames so I can build myself a player in react native?
*(fast forward, skip through selected time, play, pause, etc)*